# Rails 3.2 Active Admin, Change password while logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I've got a rails 3.2 app using active admin 0.4.3. It uses an employee model as the admin users. I've added a link to the Active Admin dashboard so the currently signed in employee can change their password if they want.

```
section :admin_tasks do
  div do
    link_to "Change Password", new_employee_password_path
  end
end
```

However when I click the link I get a flash message saying that I'm already signed in. How would I go about adding a change password dialog to the active admin section of my app?

I used `new_employee_password_path` because it's what came up in the routes and it seemed appropriate. I also tried `edit_employee_password_path` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This page in the ActiveAdmin wiki should help https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-add-User-Accounts-for-users-to-administer-their-personal-accounts